# How to click button in table cell

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button which is in a table cell. This cell contains couple of buttons.
Table has 5 rows and 10 collumns. Button cell is the last one. 
Tried using xpath tool in firefox but i am getting an exception that the element could not be found.
tried these xpath variations:

```
Drv.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='SERVICE_CANCEL']/tbody/tr[" + 4 + "]/td[10]")).Click();
Drv.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='SERVICE_CANCEL']/tr[" + 4 + "]/td[10]/div")).Click();
Drv.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@serid='10002455']/tr[4]")).Click();
```

none of these works. Also in every row's 10th cell there is a pack of buttons as i said before. Dont have any other ideas how to click it. If u could help i would appreciate it.

Because HTML code is a bit "Huge" so part of it:

```
<TR class=datagrid-row id=datagrid-row-r2-2-3 datagrid-row-index="3">
<TD style="DISPLAY: none" field="index">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-index" style="HEIGHT: auto; WHITE-SPACE: normal; TEXT-ALIGN: left">4</DIV></TD>

<TD field="name">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-name">Text1</DIV></TD>
<TD field="ID">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-ID">000</DIV></TD>
<TD field="ID2">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-ID2">111</DIV></TD>
<TD field="ID3">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-ID3"></DIV></TD>

<TD field="buttons">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-buttons" style="HEIGHT: auto; WHITE-SPACE: normal; TEXT-ALIGN: left">
<DIV class=gridbuttons><A title="shutdown" class="button enabled" id=SERVICE_CANCEL serid="10002455"></A></DIV></TD></TR>
```

Comment: share relevant part of HTML.

Comment: Typically I make a list of all the `<tr>` elements, then for each item within that list I make a list of the `<td>` elements and then interact with the cells that way.

Answer (score 1):

The button has an id (SERVICE_CANCEL). First you should rectify the HTML because you need quotes like that : `<a id="SERVICE_CANCEL">` and then just use :

```
 Drv.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("SERVICE_CANCEL")).Click();
```

You don't need any xpath when you have an id

Comment: ID won't work, because in another TR there is new set with TDs. And there is also same button with the same ID. Also i need to press not the first button which occurs but third or fifth depending on the condision.

Comment: @Shien Then your html is wrong because an id should be unique. Fix that before trying to do anyhting else

Answer (score 0):

Shien, As we cannot use IDs in a table cell value with ID(as these can be generated dynamically or not unique) you need to give the entire xpath.

I have taken your HTML and just updated the last  values You can see with ** and following is the selenium code worked for me.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" width="200px">
<TR class=datagrid-row id=datagrid-row-r2-2-3 datagrid-row-index="3">
<TD style="DISPLAY: none" field="index">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-index" style="HEIGHT: auto; WHITE-SPACE: normal; TEXT-ALIGN: left">4</DIV></TD>
<TD field="name">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-name">Text1</DIV></TD>
<TD field="ID">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-ID">000</DIV></TD>
<TD field="ID2">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-ID2">111</DIV></TD>
<TD field="ID3">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-ID3"></DIV></TD>

<TD field="buttons">
<DIV class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-buttons" style="HEIGHT: auto; WHITE-SPACE: normal; TEXT-ALIGN: left">
<DIV class=gridbuttons>**<input type=button value="shutdown" class="button enabled" id=SERVICE_CANCEL serid="10002455" onclick="calFunc()"></input>**</DIV></TD></TR>
</table>
<script>
function calFunc()
{
  alert("Hello World");
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Selenium Code in Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div/div/input[@value='shutdown']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after digging even more.
Xpath that i used was:

```
//a[contains(@id, 'SERVICE_CANCEL') and contains (@serid, '" +tempPaslaugosIDReiksme + "')]"
```